# GridView Sort and delete; Wrong row

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, postback

So I have a grid view which gets data from a database. I want to be able to sort and page this table, as well as to remove single rows.

Now the Problem: I need to bind my data every time (also on postback), else my datasource will be null when trying to sort, but by doing so I will also get the wrong row each time I try to delete (or edit) a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I thought that I had to **bind** the rows each time. **All I had to do each time is to set the DataSouce and ONLY bind if (!IsPostBack).** Then onSort i just bind again and it will be sorted. Also the delete-Function will then get the right row.